# Highlight div on .slideToggle reveal

Tags: jquery

this is my first question, so I hope I'm able to format and word it correctly.

I've just started to learn jQuery on the site codeacademy and I've been trying to create a simple application based on what I've been learning. It's a Top Trumps-style game (highly unoriginal I know) based on mayoral candidates in Bristol.

What I would like, is that when you click on one of the options on the Marvin card, the card that loads on the right (George) has the same selection highlighted. So for instance, if I choose the option 'Tweets', then it highlights the 'Tweets' option on George's card before it slideToggles on.

I have managed to get some way towards the general styling and a little of the jQuery (apologies if it's hard to understand how I may have written it) and you can see the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4vdf4/

Any thoughts on how to code some jQuery so that a highlighted selection in a separate div appears based on a user's click.

Many thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Let me be the first to say for a first time user it's a very well written question, better than some long term members!

Answering, in a simplified example, solely your question about selecting rows, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/xhAnK/1/

```
<div id="card1">
    <ul>        
        <li class="row1">Row 1</li>
        <li class="row2">Row 2</li>
        <li class="row3">Row 3</li>
        <li class="row4">Row 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="card2">
    <ul>        
        <li class="row1">Row 1</li>
        <li class="row2">Row 2</li>
        <li class="row3">Row 3</li>
        <li class="row4">Row 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div li').click(function(){

        // remove any previous selections
        $('div li').removeClass('selected'); 


        // get the class of the row you have clicked
        var strClass = $(this).attr('class'); 


        // apply the class to the other divs
        $('div li.' + strClass).addClass('selected');

    });

});​
```

So what's going on? Well basically a click on any list item will find it's partner in a similar div. I've used classes in this case so that if, for some reason, the rows appear out of order, it won't matter. Because you have fixed rows in a fixed order you could potentially track based on the position of the row rather than it's name.

Notice I've used classes rather than id's. For the same reason that you have the same rows always, it means you can simply fetch the class of the row you've clicked and use the same string to find it elsewhere. In your case, with IDs, you would have to first manipulate the ID string you've received from a clicked list item, adding '1' to the end. See your example modified: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/4vdf4/10/. Remember, you can have both ID's and classes so you can still keep the ID to correctly bind your data then simply use the classes for the selection process.

I think my answer is written a lot less carelessly than your question! Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words Chris. Also, thank you for such a good explanation. I'm very grateful for you taking the time to explain what's happening, as that is the way I will be able to learn and understand in the future. It also works like a charm. I've happened to stumble across your CSS of nth-child(even) as well, which is far better than the way I've styled my divs and I will use in the future. Thanks again, Matt

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is not very nice, but with least effort you can access corresponding list item on the second card inside your `$(".link").click` function like this:

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '1').css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: Hi Michal, apologies for my poor markup, hopefully that is something that I can revisit. Many thanks for your answer, it works perfectly. Matt

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the click code with this. and then obviously tweak it a bit.

this will target the index LI as you requested.

```
var getId;
            $("#stats li").click(function () {
                getId = $(this).index();
                $('#card1').slideToggle();
            });

            $(".link").click(function() {
                $(".link").css('color', '');
                $(".link").css('background-color', '');
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                $(this).css('color', 'white');
                $(this).addClass('picked');
                $('#stats1 ul li').eq(getId).addClass("picked");
            });
```